# How to change the url from /(id) to ?=(id)

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a url that looks like that:

```
/reservations/database/read/1641
```

How can i make it look like and the function to work under parameters:

```
/reservations/database/read?id=1641
```

What should i edit? the configuration of the routes or how the function is made?

.htaacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your "problem" lies in the .htaccess file. However, be warned that if you're using a framework you MAY brake routing completely.

Comment: can you provide .htaccess file?

Comment: @sandeepsure htaaccess

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#enabling-query-strings

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code link is generated?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this may help this to you.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And using this, to get parameters in your controller, instead of function parameters:

```
$this->input->get('id');
```

So this will work:

```
site/controller/method?parameter=value
```